# Triangles with same colored sides

Tags: combinatorics

Take $30$ noncolinear points. We connect every point to every other point, and color the line segment either red or blue. There are exactly $12$ blue line segments connected to each point, the other ones are red. How many triangles are there such that all of its sides are the same color?

Comment: How many triangles are there altogether? How many might have two blue sides, or one blue side? A relatively simple case to consider is two $K_{15}$ graphs which are all blue-edged except for one length-15 red cycle, then the two are fully connected together by red edges.